# Is there more efficient way to check the number of cases in every brach in variable?

Tags: r

For 100 000 000 rows it costs 5 sec. It is too much. Do ya know how to improve this code to get the checking faster?

```
 #a variable to check
xVar <- as.factor(sample(x=c("transp","bud","wolny","pref",
                                      "inny"), size=100000000, replace=T))

#a trigger, if a variable has less then 1000 number of cases in any branch then the variable warn will fill with a comunicat
sen <- 10000 

#function to improve
check <- function(xVar, sen){
  if (min(table(xVar)) < sen){
    warn <- "Variable has very low number in some branches - IV can be spoiled"
  }else{
    warn <- ""
  }
}

#go
start <- Sys.time()
check(xVar, sen)
stop <- Sys.time()
stop - start
```

Comment: Some sample data would be very nice.

Comment: You could improve the speed using `tabulate(xVar)`

Comment: I make a reprodictible example now.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tabulate` to improve the speed

```
check <- function(xVar, sen){
  if (min(tabulate(xVar)) < sen){
   warn <- "Variable has very low number in some branches - IV can be spoiled"
  }else{
    warn <- ""
  }
}

start <- Sys.time()
check(xVar, sen)
stop <- Sys.time()
stop - start
#Time difference of 0.272254 secs
```

With OP's function, the difference of `stop` and `start` is

```
stop - start
#Time difference of 5.077512 secs
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
xVar <- as.factor(sample(x=c("transp","bud","wolny","pref",
                                  "inny"), size=100000000, replace=T))
sen <- 10000
```